# How can I move an character in c++

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I have a problem, I want to move a character from the terminal, but do not know how. There is no conio.h library for linux, but I'm using it. Somebody can help me?

Thank you in advance as well.

Comment: You could try the ncurses library (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ncurses library. It has all sorts of nifty functions to deal with terminal I/O.

Answer (score 1):

"moving a character" doesn't always require the use of third party libraries. Sometimes you can do it with stdio and the "\b" (or backspace) character.

If you output

```
"=>"
```

Then output

```
"\b=>"
```

It will "move" the ">" character to the right and elongate the "=" line.

This is the gist of making [all kinds](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/progress.hpp) of [fancy progressbars](https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar)

Answer (score 1):

As several said, read [Ncurses Programming HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) and use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

You could also use the [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library (it is GPL licensed).

And you could use [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (but I don't recommend that), and backspace or return control characters.

You may consider coding a graphical ([Qt](http://qt-project.org/) is useful in C++) or a Web interface ([Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), [Onion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion), FastCGI, ....).

If your program needs root privilege it is better to separate the interface with the applicative thing (in two different processes communicating e.g. with pipes), notably for security reasons.